# qmail sending mail failure to wrong customers

Tags: email

this is a bit strange,

userA sends a email, userB gets it.

User A gets a failure notice saying that the message could not be delivered to userA, userB, userC, userd, userE, ect

the only recipient was userB, where is qmail getting all these other failed addresses, and why is it claiming that the mail failed?

this does not happen to all users, just some. deleting and recreating th euser does not stop the behaviour, reinstalling qmail-psa and recreating the queues does not stop it.

here is a snippet

```
---------------------------------------------
From: MAILER-DAEMON@verdehosting.com [mailto:MAILER-DAEMON@verdehosting.com]

Sent: Tuesday, November 13, 2007 4:26 PM
To: rochelle@michaelgodard.com
Subject: failure notice

Hi. This is the qmail-send program at verdehosting.com.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<robin@major.co.kr>:
Sorry, I couldn't find any host named major.co.kr. (#5.1.2)

<robin@ldsystemsinfo.com>:
64.18.5.10 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 Mailbox does not exist Giving up on 64.18.5.10.

<RodAbarcarod@aol.com>:
205.188.159.57 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 MAILBOX NOT FOUND
Giving up on 205.188.159.57.

<rocky@essex1.com>:
208.1.86.73 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 5.1.1 <rocky@essex1.com> is not a valid mailbox Giving
up on 208.1.86.73.

<robin@dunwell.com>:
208.70.89.1 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 Recipient rejected Giving up on 208.70.89.1.

<robinr@cswnet.com>:
209.235.147.38 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 <robinr@cswnet.com>...
H:MXB<66.209.80.200>Connection refused due to abuse Giving up on
209.235.147.38.

<Roblangley@northeastdigital.com>:
Sorry, I couldn't find a mail exchanger or IP address. (#5.4.4)

<rockman@surfsouth.com>:
207.69.189.217 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 rockman@surfsouth.com...User unknown Giving up on
207.69.189.217.

<rocklori@netzero.net>:
64.136.44.37 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 rocklori@netzero.net is not a valid user Giving up on
64.136.44.37.

----------------------------------------------Many more addresses snipped--------------

From: "Rochelle" <rochelle@michaelgodard.com>
To: "'Gordene Rodrigues'" <payables@signaturegalleries.net>
Subject: RE: INVOICES
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2007 16:25:38 -0800
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
boundary="----=_NextPart_000_00E2_01C82611.D3BF7AA0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook, Build 11.0.5510
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2900.3198
Thread-Index: AcgmUi7FXysH+WA0RkOYPYl6cUCikQAAYTtQ
In-Reply-To: <iun2pxsbrnrc6lp.131120071613@mail.hdiss.net>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a spam case: Someone is pretending that he is sending mail from your email addresses so when target email servers return their error they send the replies to your userA. 
Do a check for several email messages of that kind and find if Users B,C .. etc. had really sent those messages (which received the errors). If they hadn't sent them then I am right.

Comment: I tried to check as many messages as I could, but let say, you send me an email from you@yourdomain.com to me@mydoamin.com, and then you will receive an email from Mailer-Daemon saying that, your email was not able to be delivered to someoneelse@theirdomain.com as theirdomain.com does not exist. Actually you have never sent an email to theirdomain.com just to mydomain.com and email has been delivered fine. I checked the mail queue, and there are like 100 Mailer-Daemon emails generated per hour.

Comment: Ok, lets do some tests:

Comment: I am not sure why do you wanna do that, since user C does not exist. As you can see in the transcript, lets say robin@major.co.kr, this email does not exist, however I will send an email to this recipient and see  the results and post them here.

Comment: Got the bounce back straight away : 
<robin@major.co.kr>:
207.211.64.234 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 5.1.1 <robin@major.co.kr>... User unknown
Giving up on 207.211.64.234.

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Comment: 1. try to send a simple email from UserB to UserC (in your own domain) and see what you 'll get.     2. try to send a mail from UserB@yourdomain.com to some non existent mailbox but  existent domain ( example - to sads56s51dd156d5sw1we2e2@gmail.com.    3. try to send an email from UserB@yourdomain.com to non existent domain and mailbox ( example - to asdasasd@fdfwefsafds.net). See what you'll get...

Comment: I cannot post all the info here as it says there are too many characters, can I send you a message or something with the results I got?

Comment: check your domain directory and your user directory ( it depends how qmail was patched and configured but you may get some directions) for dotqmail files and their content .. there might be some aliases or dotqmail redirections configured

Comment: Sent an email to non-existent gmail account and I got a bounce back.
<oihdas@MyMailServerName.Net>:
(My server's IP) does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 <MyMailServerName.Net>... Relaying denied
Giving up on (My server's IP).
<jabrajibrabnasdawlasdjasdhw@MyMailServerName.Net>:
My server's IP does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 5.7.1 <jabrajibrabnasdawlasdjasdhw@MyMailServerName.Net>... Relaying denied
Giving up on My server's IP.
<jk@gmail.com>:
173.194.78.26 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 552-5.2.2 The email account that you tried to reach is over quota

Comment: Regarding your last comment - it looks normal ( you send to nonexistent mailbox and you receive the error message). Look my previous comment - your users and domain may have some dotqmail redirects and aliases left

Comment: Th last one might be correct, but I just checked the mail queue and there are more than 20000 Mailer-Daemon emails on the queue that were generated on the last two days :( , everything else I checked looks fine, and nothing has been changed on the server!